# How to set custom fonts in bold styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have downloaded custom font to use on my app. I want to set style bold for that font. I have used the following code but its not working:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
"fonts/BRADHITC.otf");
Typeface bold = Typeface.create(tf, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);    
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cou_text);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: one more thing, is it possible to use in xml layout? if yes then how?

Comment: in your xml for textview give android:textStyle="bold"

Comment: How can this be the solution? This doesn't even specify the custom font

Comment: How is Typeface tf is getting bold here?

Answer (score 10):

DEFAULT_BOLD is of type Typeface. Typeface.create() requires int.

Here is correct one

```
Typeface bold = Typeface.create(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these answers worked for me.

Maybe they worked for others, but the way I got the bold version of a font working in my program, I did the following:

1. Copy/pasted the font .ttc - in this case AmericanTypewriter.ttc - to a folder I created in my main/assets/ directory called /fonts. So, **main/assets/fonts/AmericanTypewriter.ttc**
2. I made sure I had a TextView with an id in my xml:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/myTextView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="This is American Bold"/>
   ```
3. At the top of my Activity, declared a TextView object:

   ```
   private TextView myTextView;
   ```
4. In the same Activity's onCreate(), inserted the following code:

   ```
   Typeface americanFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
           "fonts/AmericanTypewriter.ttc");
       Typeface americanFontBold = Typeface.create(americanFont, Typeface.BOLD);
       myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
       myTextView.setTypeface(americanFontBold);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but maybe helpful:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BRADHITC.otf"), Typeface.BOLD);
```

This way i have changed TextView appearance of `SlidingTabLayout`.